# PHP A hyperlinks thumbnails to other images

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, displayobject

Here's my php:

```
    $thumbs  = glob('images/*_thumb.jpg');
    $thumbs_number = count($thumbs);
    $watermarked = glob('images/*_watermarked.jpg');
    $watermarked_number = count($znaki);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $thumbs_number; $i++) {
    echo "<img src='$thumbs[$i]' hspace='20' />";
    }
```

I am currently displaying the thumbnails of uploaded images stored in folder images.
What I'm looking for is a way to link them to watermarked images of uploaded files.

In folder images I have 3 files:

1.jpg, 1.jpg_thumb.jpg, 1.jpg_watermarked.jpg.

So if I click the the thumbnails, it should open an watermarked image of uploaded file.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not actually a PHP question but an HTML question. Simply pack the img tag in an anchor tag that links to the watermarked picture.

EDIT: OP requested specific code so here you go:

```
echo "<a href='{$watermarked[$i]}'><img src='{$thumbs[$i]}' hspace='20' alt='Picture'/></a>";
```

Comment: '                                                        echo "<a target="_blank" href='$watermarked[$i]'><img src='$thumbs[$i]' hspace='20' alt='Picture' /></a>";
'
I tried this, but I get an error:


'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/show.php on line 18'

Comment: You need to escape your quotation marks like this: echo "<a target=\"_blank\" etc. etc.";

Comment: echo"<a href='\$watermarked[$i]\'><img src='$thumbs[$i]' hspace='20' alt='Picture' /></a>";

So it makes a hyperlink, however it doesn't proceed to watermarked image but displays an error:

The requested URL /$watermarked[0]/ was not found on this server.

Comment: You can't use arrays literally in a string. Either do `echo "blablabla" . $watermarked[$i] . "blablabla";` OR `echo "blablabla{$watermarked[$i]}blablabla";`

Comment: I really don't get this example of yours, could you be more specific?

Comment: I'm by principle against spoonfeeding code but I edited my answer anyway.